# How does this C++ while loop work?

Tags: c++, while-loop, comma-operator

I learned the basics of C++ few months ago. Recently I found a while loop that looks like this. I want to understand how it works.

```
while(cin>>n>>m,n||m)
{
    does something;
}
```

Comment: Comma operator returns the last value. `a, b` is true when `b` is true.

Comment: For *extreme* pedantry one would type `while(cin>>n>>m,void(),n||m)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator , (operator comma)` executes all instructions in list and returns value of last expression, so `cin>>n>>m,n||m` is equal to

```
cin >> n >> m;
n || m;
```

And whole loop will work like this one:

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;
while(n || m){
    //some action
    cin >> n >> m;
}
```

Comment: Although the compiler is free to execute these instructions in any order.

Comment: Um no.  In C++98 speak all of std::ostream::operator >>, comma operator, and logical or operator produce a sequence point.  There is no choice about the ordering at all.  (More recent C++ standards talk about "sequenced before/after" rather than sequence points, but the logic is the same.)

Comment: thank you for the explanation, now i understand the concept.

Comment: @ForceBru: Martin Bonner is correct. Here is the relevant text from the Draft C++ 17 standard (paragraph 5.19 Comma Operator): "A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5). Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression."

Answer (score 0):

as long as both n and m is not equal to zero the loop will run
every time it will at first execute the cin>>n>>m and then check the condition n||m

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the expression with comma is your condition. So it will evaluate the loop based on `n||m` where `n` and `m` are values read as inputs.

```
cin>>n>>m;  //Read values of n and m
while(n||m) //Check if n OR m is true
{
    does something;
    cin>>n>>m; //Read the next set of values
};
```